# Lock screen does not work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, system-settings

Lock screen does not work on Ubuntu after upgrade to 20.04. I have it turned on in tweaks and it does not work. When I click "lock" the screen simply reloads and disables some extensions in the process. It does not work at all. How can I fix this?

ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions:

```
total 80
drwxrwxr-x 20 me me 4096 May 10 09:32 .
drwx------  3 me me 4096 May 25 15:58 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 Jun  6  2019 appfolders-manager@maestroschan.fr
drwxr-xr-x  3 me me 4096 Mar 14 07:08 appindicatorsupport@rgcjonas.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May 10 09:30 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  4 me me 4096 Dec 12 14:55 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 Jun  7  2019 clock-override@gnomeshell.kryogenix.org
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May  9 22:17 customcorner@eccheng.gitlab.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 May  9 22:13 custom-hot-corners@janrunx.gmail.com
drwxr-xr-x  5 me me 4096 Apr 29 16:20 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May 10 09:31 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 Apr 21  2019 fq@megh
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May 10 09:30 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May  9 22:14 night-light-slider.timur@linux.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May 10 09:31 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 me me 4096 Nov 28 12:00 removeaccesibility@lomegor
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 May  9 22:14 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me 4096 May  9 22:15 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May  9 22:15 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 me me 4096 May 10 09:32 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions:

```
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Oct 29  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 May 23 10:13 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.c
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added the info you asked for as a screenshot cuz I couldn't figure out how to make this respect newlines. It kept sticking everything together - both in "blockquote" and "code".

Comment: To copy/paste the output of my commands, copy the output to the clipboard, edit your question, paste in the clipboard, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format it. Please see my partial answer. Do it and report back. Please remember to start comments to me with @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for the help. I just saw this after the answer so comment there is not editing to add your name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Holy !@#$% batman! You've got WAY too many GNOME Shell extensions, and many of them overlap in functionality.

**First step...**

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable **ALL** extensions, then restart GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then retest the lock screen, and see if it works normally.

**Second step...**

Let's start by cleaning out your `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`...

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax.github.com
```

Restart the GNOME Shell using the previous instructions.

This should leave you with these extensions in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`...

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May  9 18:04 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Using the same web location that I gave earlier, REMOVE any remaining extensions that you either 1) don't really need, or 2) overlap in functionality. Then re-enable the remaining extensions one-at-a-time to see if one of them causes your lock screen problem. Restart the GNOME Shell after each disable/enable/remove(s) change.

Comment: You are correct....Robin :) it works now. I saw 68 and 80 in the readout of what you asked for, but I only have 24 extensions (showing in tweaks) and about a third are disabled. I guess I should re-enable one by one now and test where the problem is, right?

Comment: @i9pp0 Please see the Second Step in my answer.

Comment: I did what you said, and then re-enabled the extensions I want. Everything works correctly now. Thank you for your help. I will do some testing to find out which ones were conflicting.

Comment: Aaaaaaaa I forgot your name again....and it won't let me add it - again!

Comment: @i9pp0 You don't have to add my name if you're responding to my answer... only above, after your question :-)

Comment: @i9pp0 Also, to see if extension are still causing problems, do `grep -i stack /var/log/syslog*`, and any "Stack trace" errors from gnome-shell are probably bad extension errors.

Comment: Ah, ok. This UI is a little couterintuitive...And thanks for the extension tip!