# Gnome-screensaver seg fault, can't lock session

Tags: gnome, 20.04, lock-screen, screensaver

Upgraded from 19.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell XPS 9350. There are no screensaver options in Settings or in gnome tweaks. Screen lock doesn't work, it quits the gnome session instead and gives me login screen.

If I run `gnome-screensaver --debug` I get this output:

```
[gs_debug_init] gs-debug.c:106 (15:59:44):   Debugging enabled
[main] gnome-screensaver.c:86 (15:59:44):    initializing gnome-screensaver 3.6.1
[query_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:1471 (15:59:44):   Couldn't determine our own session id: No data available
[init_session_id] gs-listener-dbus.c:1518 (15:59:44):    Got session-id: (null)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Running `gnome-screensaver-command -l` causes my gnome session to quit immediately.

How can I get gnome screensaver to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Problem was caused by a conflict with a gnome extension. See solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243552/1070812).

Thanks to @i9pp0 for the question and @heynnema for the answer.