# Black screen after lock and not unlockable 20.04

Tags: lock-screen

After locking my computer, I cannot unlock it. I have had this effect since installing the new system. After locking, the computer does not respond to the mouse or keyboard, it is turned on, but the login screen is not displayed.

The only solution is to turn off the computer and turn it on again.

Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit Wayland
Dell latitude 5490

Does anyone know maybe solving this problem?

Comment: I found this regarding screen lock : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243491/lock-screen-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-20-04#1243552  See if this is possibly contributing to your issue

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: I have similar problem, but after update to Ubuntu 21.10. Found this solution https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456023

Comment: I have a similar problem. suspend/unsuspend works, but automatic screen blank makes the computer unrecoverable (doesn't respond to ctrl-alt-del, alt-f1 > alt-f2 etc.). Had it earlier too, I think I've changed some bios power management stuff to make it go away. Recently I've experimented with BIOS some more while installing new RAM, and the issue is back. I imagine my issue must be related to wake up settings or power management settings.

Comment: I've examined some logs and found out this was my issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1819 - I hope getting a mainline kernel will fix it. Comments suggest it was fixed in kernel 5.17.9

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem on 22.04 LTS by switching to the lastest version of proprietary Nvidia driver and X11 windowing system. By the way, it solved another problem - suspend problem. Maybe it will help you.

[ubuntu 22.04 can't suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)