# Ubuntu 22.04 suspend improper working

Tags: suspend, 22.04

I had updated to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04. Everything was normal but sometimes suspend is not working accordingly. It shows a black screen as shown in the attachment. And it doesn't revoke or respond to any keyboard or mouse strokes.
I have to force shutdown and restart again. Please help me fix this. [image: imagep.04]

Comment: Do you have any progress on this? I have a similar problem on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 carbon 4th generation. Is lenovo working fine otherwise?

Comment: @Vam, there is an update from launchpad and i've posted the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406114/cant-login-after-suspend-with-nouveau-wayland-22-04/1406212#1406212)

Comment: So, for now it seems like new bug in Ubuntu 22.04.

Steps to try to fix:
- try change X11 to Wayland and backwards
- if you have nvidia GPU, [check this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)
- if you have integrated card - confirm that this bug affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957