# can't login after suspend with Nouveau + wayland_22.04

Tags: nvidia, login, suspend, 22.04, nouveau

I am having suspend issues for 22.04, hence, is testing different combinations of x11/wayland with different drivers. And I found out that I am unable to login after suspend when using the Nouveau + wayland combination. The system prompted for password, however, after entering the password, the loading icon pops up and loads forever. Tried clicking on it and the password prompt disappears and is left with the login screen without the prompt. The topbar icons and selections are still available, hence, is able to reboot or shutdown. This is the only combination that has this login issue among other combinations.

FYI, I am only able to run without suspend issues using Nividia 390 driver and wayland option is not available by default for 390. And suspend issues (black screen, black screen with codes, etc...) persist with Nividia 510 driver on both wayland and X11.

Kindly advise

Answer (score 9):

Got an update from the launchpad. There is a work around for Nividia 510 using the solution from Nividia 470.

Disable NVIDIA systemd services

```
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service
```

Remove NVIDIA systemd script

```
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia
```

Reboot and you should be able to suspend and resume properly with driver 510 for 22.04 for both x11 and wayland

The original workaround was for 470. However, I've tested it and the solution works for 510 on 22.04 with x11 and wayland.

Original solution with details can be found [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fixed-suspend-resume-issues-with-the-driver-version-470/187150/2?u=cirosantilli) by contributor "humblebee". And bug report on launchpad can be found [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-470/+bug/1946303)

Comment: This also worked for me. After upgrading to 22.04, system would freeze completely (i.e. no NumLock) trying to resume from suspend, but only if the power was unplugged. Works perfectly after following these steps.

Comment: When I run `sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service` it says "Failed to stop nvidia-suspend.service: Unit nvidia-suspend.service not loaded." I can't find suspend and resume services in my Ubuntu 22. What can I do?