# not waking up from suspend ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, 22.04, wakeup

I just upgrade my Lenovo X1 Carbon from Ubuntu 20.04.4 to 22.04. Before, I could wake up from suspend by either opening the lid or by pressing the power bottom. Now, after upgrading, I cannot wake up from suspend at all! I need to force shutdown that is very annoying.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
N1FET74W (1.48 )
           
free -h
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         15Gi        1,7Gi        11Gi       526Mi      2,4Gi        12Gi
Swap:        2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi

sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/swapfile               file        2097148     0           -2
```

UPDATE 2:

```
$ lsmod | grep -i think
think_lmi              28672  0
firmware_attributes_class    16384  1 think_lmi
thinkpad_acpi         122880  0
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,thinkpad_acpi
snd                   102400  21 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
platform_profile       16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
wmi                    32768  2 wmi_bmof,think_lmi
video                  53248  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Newly installed 22.04 on a ThinkPad t460s
Tried switching between x.org and wayland. Only integrated graphics

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136098/discussion-on-question-by-user1571823-not-waking-up-from-suspend-ubuntu-22-04).

Comment: So, for now it seems like new bug in Ubuntu 22.04.

Steps to try to fix:
- try change X11 to Wayland and backwards
- if you have nvidia GPU, [check this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)
- if you have integrated card - confirm that this bug affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957

Comment: Had the same issue on a Thinkpad L460. Deactivating the `Security chip` also let the laptop wake up from suspend again. Not sure which downsides deactivating the chip on Ubuntu has.

Comment: Try to reset BIOS

Comment: if you have nvidia 470 driver installed that could cause this. For a workaround see: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fixed-suspend-resume-issues-with-the-driver-version-470/187150/2

Answer (score 6):

I was pulling my hair out over this same issue on a Lenovo t460s. I got it to work by going into BIOS, under the `Security` tab, and disabling Security Chip.

Now suspend and power off both work great on 22.04. Good luck!

Comment: Worked for me on a T460s, the question is why? And what changed between 21:10 and 22:04 to break such a critical feature?

Comment: [Launchpad activity](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1971437) suggests that something was changed in the kernel source code and/or compile options. As far as why "such a critical feature" broke, I don't know what to say other than: _this is pretty typical for Linux and open source in general_.

Comment: Didn't work out on an X1 Carbon, ubuntu 22.10. Any assumptions on why this would work in the first place btw?

Comment: I don't see the Security Chip option in BIOS. Is it only in Lenovo?

Answer (score 5):

If you have NVidia graphics card try this: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/brightness-not-working-ubuntu-20-04-lenovo-legion-5-15imh05/178058/21

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and add `nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

Then execute:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

The computer recovers from suspension but your display brightness its zero.

Comment: While this is great news (and I can confirm it is one of the problems I faced numerous times) it does not solve the exact issue I am having and probably same thing OP is facing.

When waking up the PC goes completely unresponsive, sometimes keyboard leds are stuck, even trying to switch to other sessions with CTRL+ALT+Fn has no use.
Only way is to force shutdown by keeping the power button pressed until it shuts down.

Comment: Tried it - doesn't work. ThinkPad P1 Gen3 (Ubuntu certified FFS). Tested NVidia graphics 510.

Comment: This one does not work for me. Mine still gets stuck at the dell logo forever.

Comment: I hoped this would work because my laptop actually wakes up (I can hear notifications sound when opening the lid) with apparently just black screen, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for was disabling Wayland by editing the file: `etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Section of the file:

```ini
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue at Lenovo X1 Carbon 4th on Ubuntu 22.04.

Steps to fix:

1. At the booting screen press `"F1"` to enter into bios.
2. Choose `"Security"` tab.
3. Find `"Security chip"` and `disable` it.
4. Press `"Save and exit"`.
5. Enjoy suspend and power off :)

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1412049/

Comment: Can Secure Boot remain enabled with the Security Chip disabled? Do I need to do anything else in the BIOS besides disabling the Security Chip if I have UEFI set to Secure Boot?

Comment: @G.W. no, in my case, the steps described above were enough.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here with an LG Gram 17Z990. It does not resume from suspend. The power light is on, so I could not say if the problem is suspending or awaking back on.

I edited `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and added `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` to momentarily workaround it. Yet, I still have not tested the workaround.

Comment: "systemctl hibernate" hangs in the same fashion. Not sure but it looks like the display wakes up without backlight or some problem with the driver (intel) waking up. I have a hackintosh installed in this machine, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with a Lenovo X1 Yoga, does not wake up from Sleep.

For me also disabling the Security Chip in BIOS settings "solved" the problem (but this prevents Windows from using the PIN login method).

When trying the Live Kubuntu image from USB stick, booting using UEFI instead of legacy BIOS was required (with disabled Security Chip), so it seems both UEFI and disabled Security Chip is necessary to make it work.