# Ubuntu 22.04 not waking up after second suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend, wakeup

After the first suspend it wakes up just fine - it's the **second** suspend after which the screen stays blank and keyboard doesn't react (although the power LED starts glowing). It happens if I close the laptop's lid or do a manual suspend via the system menu.

I have a recent Thinkpad T14s with a Ryzen CPU, Ubuntu 22.04 is the only OS (if that's important).

What I tried:

- turn off security chip in the BIOS (https://askubuntu.com/a/1412049/424896)
- turn off Wayland and enable X11 (https://askubuntu.com/a/1412032/424896)
- I looked through the logs in /var/log but couldn't find anything obvious to me (but I'm not a Linux guru).

Anyone has an idea what might help here?

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ah, okay. Not sure which one though? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy?

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow directions.

Comment: Okay, my first Ubuntu bug report. Let's see what happens :) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2008774

Comment: I have the same issue, and still can't fix it...

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled over this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/lnyrt6/til_i_learn_newer_thinkpads_have_a_setting_for). There is a "Sleep State" switch in the BIOS of some Thinkpads (including mine): Config ➜ Power ➜ Sleep State ➜ "Linux" / "Windows 10". I just turned it from "Windows" to "Linux" and it works now.