# how can I get my dell xps 13 to reawaken from sleep after I upgraded to 23.04?

Tags: suspend, dell, xps, 23.04

I recently upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04.

When the screen sleeps I can't wake it up again. The screen is just black.

Any ideas?

I tried looking at [not waking up from suspend ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404856/not-waking-up-from-suspend-ubuntu-22-04)

but it didn't work in this case