# Ubuntu 22.04 Black Screen after closing lid and opening back

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my HP Pavilion 15 today. Among other issues, Whenever I close my laptop lid (it should ideally suspend and work normal whenever I open it back). But On opening lid there is just a black screen there is no effect of any input from keyboard or mouse. My only choice is to force shut down pc using power off button. Also, Another time I tried just leaving the lid closed for about an hour. And after opening my laptop it was very hot which probably means that the laptop is not going to sleep after closing Lid. Please suggest some fix. Thanks!!

P.S:- Please Stop giving version updates if they are not compatible. This is my 3rd time I had to completely remove and reinstall ubuntu as update from 21.10 to 22.04 broke my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, for now it seems like new bug in Ubuntu 22.04.

Steps to try to fix:

- try change X11 to Wayland and backwards
- if you have nvidia GPU, [check this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)
- if you have integrated card - confirm that this bug affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957

Comment: Thank You for the response but I after several days of waiting I decided to revert back to 20.04 LTS to avoid losing data. However I do have a nvidia MX450 GPU as well as intel i5 11th gen cpu which has integrated graphics. I hope this solution can help others fix the issue :).