# Any Ubuntu 22.04 software freezes every time the laptop lid opens

Tags: suspend, 22.04, budgie, lid

I have a Toshiba Satellite A305-S6905 whose previous software was Ubuntu 22.04 and is currently running on Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 and every time I try to open the laptop lid, It freezes no matter what. I have tried the REISUB shortcut and it initially worked, but over time it stopped working. This was also happening on the old Ubuntu software that the same laptop was running on. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: So, for now it seems like new bug in Ubuntu 22.04.

Steps to try to fix:
- try change X11 to Wayland and backwards
- if you have nvidia GPU, [check this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend)
- if you have integrated card - confirm that this bug affects you: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970957