# Suspend only locks the screen

Tags: suspend, 22.04

I seem to have problems with suspending on Ubuntu 22.04, when I press the power button which I have bound to suspend, the screen just locks (generally happens with suspend), now, I have found a few posts about this somewhere, but none of the solutions worked, then, when I close the lid, it is also supposed to suspend, but, when I open the lid, the screen just starts blinking and after a while I see the login screen. What would I do here?
I have somehow found out about pm-suspend and it does the right thing except for locking the screen before suspending. How would I use pm-suspend or fix the normal suspend?

EDIT: gpu: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)

In case of graphics, I have integrated graphics which do most of the stuff and an NVIDIA GeForce MX150 that seems to go through integrated graphics or something. It doesn't have an output, just does stuff and probably sends it to integrated. I have an HDMI port but it seems to be just an internal DP connection to the integrated graphics afaik.

Comment: The command `lspci | grep VGA` would tell us, which graphics card you have.(It might be its driver)  Copy the output of the terminal command into your question (**not** in a comment, just to keep the infos in one place)

Comment: @kanehekili It outputs "00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)"
I do also have an NVIDIA GeForce MX150 which is afaik going through the integrated graphics.

Comment: Which graphics card driver do you use? (find it in additional driver) Are you using wayland or Xorg? (find it by typing the command echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE). Try to install nvidia's proprietary driver: https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_nvidia_ppa/

Comment: If you have a Nvidia, why isn't it shown? We are looking at hardware - nothing goes through it....

Comment: @kanehekili That is the thing, nothing goes through it, just in and back, it has no outputs as I am on a laptop. Stuff only happens on it and then the integrated graphics display it or something

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 the echo command reports x11. I am already using the proprietary driver for my NVIDIA graphics card, selected it manually on NVIDIA's website.

Comment: You could try to switch to `wayland` (from the lock screen when you choose user you have a wheel at the bottom right of the screen). You should also disable nvidia service (it works for me): `systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service nvidia-resume.service nvidia-suspend.service`: see this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403741/ubuntu-22-04-cant-suspend/1404116#1404116

Comment: @GuillaumeF93 I tried to switch to wayland, it just doesn't log in though, the screen just goes dark for the animation and I am at the login screen again. As for the nvidia service disabling, it says the services are masked and ignoring.

Comment: I think you should try an other driver: go in `additional driver`, i guess you are using the last nvidia driver: `nvidia-driver-510` select a previous version `nvidia-driver-470-server` for instance, then restart and try to suspend. If it doesn't work select an even older one. And so on.

Comment: I honestly doubt it would be with the driver, also, any other driver than the proprietary from nvidia's website seems to be broken in some way, one doesn't have proper settings, changing a thing just renders my installation broken until I reinstall the right driver, and some won't install at all. @GuillaumeF93